# Micro-intradermal spasms in the legs after exercise

Tags: muscles, skin, reflexes

Heyo !

When i'm doing physical effort that involves and then rest, I feel small and suddle of what feels like contraction all over my legs (but not feet); It stops by itself after a few minutes and there's no pain at all, just a strange sensation. It's like having pin and needle when coming and ending, but it's less "noisy" and more precise in each "contraction" and can it really feel things are moving/contractiong/whatever but I can't see anything with my eyes.

The things, they are so small in "size" and strengh and too shallow to be muscle while being too deep to be skin. From the sensations, my best guess is blood vessels exploding but don't have any bruises. My other hypothesis is dermis doing some folky things but yeah, no idea...

Thus my question: What is this thing ?

Comment: Pins and needles are different from tiny spasms, which are called fasciculations. In either case, it's certainly *not* caused by exploding blood vessels, which would leave a mark resembling a bruise, as RBC's and the heme group from RBCs can migrate through tissue pretty easily and, more importantly, blood vessels aren't given to exploding like that. Read about fasciculations and discuss it with your doctor. Sometimes there is a medical cause.

Comment: Thanks ! Can you put your comment as an answer so I valide it ?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood before. No, I cannot put it as an answer because we don't provide answers to questions seeking medical advice. Note I only gave you a term to research, and reassured you that blood vessels aren't given to behaving as you wondered about.

Comment: I wasn't seeking medical advice, I just wantd to know what were these...

Comment: i was resting and looking at my leg the other day, and there were little muscular contractions in the thigh muscles, i thought they were a heartbeat at first and actually they were just random little movements inside the thigh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has commented by @anongoodnurse, it's called fasciculation.